# Applying css with out class name

Tags: css, xml

I have a xml file with content

```
<ul>
   <li><info>CSS text formatting </info></li>
</ul>
```

Where info is a class name in css.When i parse the xml and displayed on a page the css class info is applying on the `<li>` tag.This is working in mozilla.But ie is not taking it as a css class.Is their any method to do in IE

Comment: you need to show what the end HTML looks like and what your CSS looks like so we can help you

Comment: Can you post actual HTML code. Class property on li is valid in IE

Comment: Since you say this works in Mozilla, I assume that by "CSS class" you mean "CSS type selector" as opposed to "HTML class" or "CSS class selector"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that `<info>` is not HTML.

Firefox recovers by adding it to the DOM anyway, and you can persuade IE to do the same with `document.createElement('info')`.

The correct solution, however, is to transform your XML source into HTML instead of just dropping it into the page.